# swiper button style with styled-components

Tags: styled-components, swiper.js

I want to replace button style with a style-component
What is the way?

```
<SC.CarouselBox 
        loop={true} 
        cssMode={true} 
        navigation={true} 
        mousewheel={true} 
        keyboard={true}
        slidesPerView={1} 
        pagination={{
          "clickable": true
        }} 
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        <SC.CarouselBlur></SC.CarouselBlur>
        {sliderItems.map((item, i) =>  (
          <SwiperSlide
           <img src={item.img}/>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </SC.CarouselBox>
```

i am add swiper components in styled-components, because i want change swiper style
but I can not add a button because the button is not given as a component

```
const CarouselBox = styled(Swiper)`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-grid;
`;

const Btn = styled('button')`
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a separate button:

```
navigation={{
   nextEl: ".swiper-next",
   prevEl: ".swiper-prev",
}}


<SC.Btn className="swiper-next">
   next
</SC.Btn>
<SC.Btn className="swiper-prev">
   back
</SC.Btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is slightly different. You don't need to wrap your button in brackets like a string. Instead you should write your code like this:

```
const Btn = styled.button`
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
`;
```